# JMSSerializer - how to pass timezone to serialization

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have setted timezone in `php.ini` file to `UTC` but in my app I have `Europe/Warsaw`.

The question is: How to pass that 2nd timezone to JMS to use it for serialization `\DateTime` objects?
I have tried something like this:

```
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone); //Europe/Warsaw
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        $data = $serializer->serialize($shift, 'json');
```

but it seems that in the first place `JMS` is looking for timezone in `php.ini` file because it returns `\DateTime` objects in format like this:

```
created_at:"2017-03-23T09:21:45+0000"
date:"2017-03-24T00:00:00+0000"
```

Comment: It may help to try to always specify the correct timezone when sending data to your backend, then you convert it to UTC and save it in the DB in UTC. When retrieving the data, JMSSerializer will give you the correct DateTime in UTC, then in your app you convert the DateTime from UTC to the user's timezone for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom accessor
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor
You can assign a different timezone in the getter and convert it back to UTC with a setter;

Comment: My timezone is dynamic and i am storing it in the db

Comment: How do you store the timezone? I had similar issue, the timezone was in another entity so I simple kept reference to that entity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue registering a new `DateHandler` on `SerializerBuilder::create()`

```
SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->configureHandlers(function(\JMS\Serializer\Handler\HandlerRegistry $registry) {
        $registry->registerSubscribingHandler(new \JMS\Serializer\Handler\DateHandler(\DateTime::ISO8601, 'America/Sao_Paulo'));
    })
```

This is the default signature for `DateHandler`:

```
public function __construct($defaultFormat = \DateTime::ISO8601, $defaultTimezone = 'UTC', $xmlCData = true)
```

So it uses UTC by default regardless of what is set on php.ini.

Comment: Please note that default value for `$defaultFormat` has changed to `\DateTime::ATOM`